# Correctly load JSON file content to an array of custom class objects in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to load quiz questions from a JSON file (called Questions.json) with the following structure:

```
{
"Questions":[
                {
                    "questionText": "Is this a question?",
                    "correctAnswer": "Yes",
                    "wrongAnswer1": "No",
                    "wrongAnswer2": "Nope",
                    "wrongAnswer3": "Maybe",
                    "wrongAnswer4": "Unclear"
                },
                {
                   "questionText": "Is this also a question?",
                    "correctAnswer": "Yes",
                    "wrongAnswer1": "No",
                    "wrongAnswer2": "Nope",
                    "wrongAnswer3": "Maybe",
                    "wrongAnswer4": "Unclear"
                }
                ]}
```

I want every question (with the question text and all answer options) to be loaded into my Question class that contains all the attributes that are in the JSON as well (questionText, correctAnswer and so on)

And I am trying to load it into the array "questions" with this code:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Questions", ofType: "json")
    {
        var jsonData: NSData?
        do {
            jsonData = try  NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
        } catch _ as NSError {

        }

        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                {
                    print(jsonResult)
                    var questions : [Question] = [Question]()
                    questions = jsonResult["Questions"]! as! [Question]
                    print(questions[0].questionText) // ERROR HERE!
                }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    }
```

When I try to print the first question text I get this error: "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type"

Do you see what is wrong here? Is it even a good way of storing the questions?

Comment: You have to actually parse each question object from the "Questions" array, they don't get deserialized from JSON to your model automatically.

Comment: Not sure if it'd be overkill for your particular project, but these libraries are very good at conveniently mapping objects from JSON https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper and https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33035482/2227743